# Shortcut for toggling hidden files in Finder with AZERTY layout

Tags: macos, high-sierra

There's a shortcut for toggling the hidden files in Finder that works on QWERTY layouts: SHIFT + CMD + '.'

However, on my AZERTY layout (Belgian more specifically) this doesn't work. If I switch to a QWERTY layout, the shortcut works, so you'l be able to test it if you switch to a AZERTY layout. Anybody any idea? I'm on High Sierra.

Comment: I am on El Capitan, so the shortcut works only in the file open dialog. I tried to add the Belgian layout and obviously the '.' is located in a different position than the Italian QWERTY (two places right of the N), as I can see by showing the keyboard from the menu item. But for me, using the Belgian layout, the shortcut works.

Comment: I actually never tried it in an open file dialog but the shortcut works there indeed! Very strange that the exact same shortcut does nothing in a regular Finder window,...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Finder use this combination: *shift+cmd+fn+.*

Comment: Actually `cmd+fn+.` or `shift+cmd+fn+;` as you have to press `shift+;` to get `.`.  I knew what you meant though, thanks.

Comment: what if you have no fn button? I use a normal keyboard, not an apple keyboard.